# SQL Join Syntax with three tables with a left join

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables T1, T2, T3 the relations are:
T1 one to many on T2 (Field T2.ID1 -> T1.ID)
T3 one to many on T2 (Feild T2,ID2 -> T3,ID)

What I need are all records from T1, only those records from T2 where T2.ID1 is equal to T1.ID and the record from T3 where T2.ID3 = T3.ID

The situation is T1 is a list of parts, T2 a list of order lines, T3 is the order header.  The first relation is any part (T1) can appear on many order lines (T2), the second relation is for any order line (2) there is only one order header (T3) but and order header could have many lines.

What I have got so far is:

```
SELECT ar.customer_id,
    ar.invnumber,
    ar.transdate,
    invoice.qty,
    parts.partnumber,
    parts.description,
    parts.rop,
    parts.bin,
    parts.obsolete,
    parts.partsgroup_id,
    parts.onhand
FROM (parts LEFT JOIN invoice ON 
     parts.id = invoice.parts_id) 
    INNER JOIN ar ON invoice.trans_id = ar.id
```

But his is not giving me any of the parts that are not on any order lines at all.  PARTS = T1, ORDER LINES = T2, AR = T3

Comment: perhaps if you explicitly explained which table is which. saying t1/t2/t3 is all fine and dandy, but you're not using those names in the query. use the ACTUAL names you have in the query, or say `t1 = ar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're doing the inner join after the left join. The inner join is then discarding the results of the left join that don't have a match on T3.
Try this FROM clause and let me know:

```
FROM (invoice INNER JOIN ar ON invoice.trans_id = ar.ID) 
      RIGHT JOIN parts ON parts.id = invoice.parts_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `INNER JOIN` `orderline` with `AR` and `LEFT JOIN` the `Parts`

```
SELECT ar.customer_id,
ar.invnumber,
ar.transdate,
invoice.qty,
parts.partnumber,
parts.description,
parts.rop,
parts.bin,
parts.obsolete,
parts.partsgroup_id,
parts.onhand
FROM ar
INNER JOIN invoice ON invoice.trans_id = ar.id
LEFT JOIN parts ON parts.id = invoice.parts_id
```